# Reading text in columns from HTML tables

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I've been debugging for some time, trying to get the value of a column in a table. I think once I've done this, it should be easy to pass the value in the next column out of my JS function.

My HTML table is:

```
<table id="country_LE_table" style = "display:none">
    <tr>
      <td>Japan</td>
      <td>83.7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Switzerland</td>
      <td>83.4</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

My Javascript is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function getLifeExpectancy() {
        var Country = "<?php echo $Country ?>";
        document.write(Country); // this gets read OK
        var table = document.getElementById("country_LE_table");
        var tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
        document.write(tr.length); document.write("<br>"); // works as expected

        for (var i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {

            document.write(tr[i].innerHTML); document.write("<br>"); // works well up to here
            // the following doesn't work
            var td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
            if (td = Country) { //need td.fullHTML/value/fullText?
                return tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1]; // return the number
            }
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = getLifeExpectancy();
</script>
```

If I do `document.write(td)`, I get `"[object HTMLTableCellElement]"` on my page.
If I do `document.write(td.fullHTML)` I get `"undefined"` on my page.

When I explore other methods than td.innerHTML, I get this - it looks like I can't use functions based around text.

[image: It looks like I can't use text-functions to get the contents of the row/column element.]

Comment: `td` in your code is a reference to the cell element itself, you've to read `textContent` or `innerHTML` property of that element. Also, `document.write` is purposed to create new documents, not manipulating existing ones.

Comment: Please stop guessing, you'll never get anything finished, if you're guessing property names. Read [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableCellElement), learn, and just start to code ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this instead. you have used assignment operator instead of comparison operator "=="

```
if (td.innerHTML == Country)
    {
    }
```

Comment: This worked, along with 
document.getElementById("demoTD").innerHTML = td.textContent;